# Is it possible to undo MinMaxScaler after datacleansing?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-cleaning, undo

When I scaled my df with a MinMaxScaler. Is it possible to undo it after Data cleansing? Or what's the practical approach?

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you know the min and max before scaling, then yes. If you don't, then no.

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking to do. You could `reindex` the initial frame based on the remaining values in the cleansed frame. Sample data, source code, and expected output would be helpful to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: I guess you means the `inverse_transform` method? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform